# Any reason CSS 'display: none;' should crash Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, svg, crash

I'm working on building a web-based app that uses "floating" pop-up divs to emulate windows and right-click menus.  Whenever I "close" (hide) a div using CSS (display:none) there's a 50/50 chance that Firefox crashes.

I looked at the crash logs, and the line (of the ff source code) that breaks is one that's trying to determine whether or not I have 'pointer-events: none' on a given object... or that's what it looks like.

It seems to happen in any case where I manipulate an svg element with javascript then and apply display:none to something else either right before or right after the manipulation.  Any delay in between the svg change and the css change (break point, alert box, etc) usually prevents the crash.

Has anyone else run into anything like this, or knows why it might happen?

Comment: it's probably a bug in firefox, anyway could you post some code with that?

Comment: Did you debug Firefox to check if it really is that line of code that crashes? Whether you're not actually using `pointer-events: none` in your code, you may want to report it as an issue anyway.

Comment: Code & version of firefox because this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Firefox is version 15.0.1, but it also happens in every other build I've tried (14, beta, aurora, etc).  Unfortunately, I can't post enough of the code for it to be relevant, because I haven't been able to re-create the issue anywhere other than in this one massive project, so I don't know which piece of code would be relevant.  It's very much possible I've done something stupid somewhere... but I've not found what yet.

Comment: https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/cc26a06f-0337-4585-b434-6877a2120928